# Backbone.js '#' route not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my routers, I've specified router '#' to call the index function. This works the first time when the app loads. But after navigation away and then going back, the view no longer renders. Here's my router:

```
CommunityApp.Routers.Main = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        '#': 'index',
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.communities = new CommunityApp.Collections.Communities();
        this.communities.fetch();
    },

    index: function() {
        console.log('index called');
        view = new CommunityApp.Views.CommunitiesIndex({collection: this.communities});
        $('#main').html(view.render().el);
    }
});
```

I see that the function is called because it logs 'index called'. However the view is only rendered the first time i navigation to localhost:3000/#. If I click somewhere else which leads back to '#', the function gets called but CommunitiesIndex view never gets inserted in the DOM.

Thanks

Comment: don't know if it will fix your problem, but you don't use '#' in your routes; each route is what occurs after the '#', so a route of '#' maps to a URL of `http://domain.com/##`.

Comment: so for default, should it be just ''?

Comment: Yes, your default route should just be `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but I'll add my 2 cents.

The corresponding route is `''`.

```
routes: { '' : 'index' }
```

The route is just blank. The second part can be whatever you want, i.e. `'index'`, `'home'`, `'landing'`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use # to map the index page，this is not a good way.
I recommend that you use other characters to map the index page, such as the "index".
If you have to use #, your url should of is **http://xxx.com/##**, so it looks very strange, far better than **http://xxx.com/#index** the index clarity.

Edit:

```
 routes: {
        '': 'index'
    },
```

To do so, This means that if no matching mapping, it will automatically match ['': 'index'].That you wondering why only the first jump to the index?I would like for the first time did not match any map, so in line with ['': 'index'] to automatically jump to the index page, the future always have matching mapping, does not meet ['': 'index'] is, of course, would not jump to the index page.

Comment: Ok, but that still doesn't answer my question. When the user first open the page, http://xxx.com/ what is the corresponding route for that? just ''? what should that display? I want that to show the index.